# Why would I get ORA-01422 error while inserting a single row using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I see **many** related questions about this particular error - most of them having to do with `SELECT INTO` operations.

In this case though, I'm trying to insert a single row and don't find any answers to this particular issue.

I'm using the following code:

```
final String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO XMLTYPETEST_XMLTYPE (ACTIVITYGUID, XMLDATA) VALUES (:1, XMLType(:2))";
final String guid = "BFACFEB-8ACE-4145-B04A-759822E0AA7D";
final String xml = "<Activity><Changes></Changes></Activity>";
try (OraclePreparedStatement stmt = 
        (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL)) {
    stmt.setString(1, guid);
    stmt.setString(2, xml);
    stmt.execute();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionTest.class.getName())
          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    fail();
}
```

The table XMLTYPETEST_XMLTYPE is defined as follows:

```plsql
  CREATE TABLE "PLAYGROUND"."XMLTYPETEST_XMLTYPE" 
   (    "ACTIVITYGUID" CHAR(36 BYTE), 
    "XMLDATA" "XMLTYPE"
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "XMLDATA" STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE LOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ALLOW NONSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA ;


Name          Type           
------------  -------------- 
ACTIVITYGUID  CHAR(36)       
XMLDATA       PUBLIC.XMLTYPE
```

I've tried various combinations of objects and `set*()` methods for setting the XMLData parameter as well as using `executeUpdate()`, all with the same result:

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

In case there's any clue in the library versions, here are the relevant dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/xdb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/xmlparserv2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this piece of code raises the error? Is there, perhaps, any trigger on the target table which *does something*, and it raises the error?

Comment: Doubtful that there's a trigger. I created the table myself just for the purpose of comparing tables with XMLType vs CLOB. Added table DDL in original question.    The error occurs at the stmt.execute() line.

Answer (score 0):

The more I thought about it, the more suspicious the mismatched library versions were.  I replaced two libraries with the following versions:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdb6</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

That fixed the problem.  /facepalm